# SessionAwareCoreServiceClient connection state Faulted in 2013 Core Service

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service, network

We have serious problems trying to connect to Core Service (2013) with one of our clients (with both wshttp and netTcp). The only difference in this case is that this client has a proxy, but proxy is bypassed for local connections (and this is a plugin installed in the same CM, so we don't need any proxy).

Service host is running, and everything seems to be set correctly, but we get the next error. What does that Proxies.RealProxy means, if we are not setting any proxy there?

Thank you so much. Any help will be really appreciated.

---

> 2020-10-20 15:32:38 [ERROR] The communication object,
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for
> communication because it is in the Faulted state.
> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The
> communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel,
> cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
> Server stack trace:    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan
> timeout)   Exception rethrown at [0]:    at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
> msgData, Int32 type)    at
> System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan
> timeout)

[UPDATE]

I've managed to connect via net.tcp. There was a problem with user credentials, so I ensure the impersonation user was a valid Tridion administrator user.

The problem now is trying to connect via wshttp. Seems like service host is trying to use the same port as Tridion. If I go the the address 'http://localhost:81/webservices/CoreService2013.svc/wsHttp', I get the following message.

```
This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. If your service is being hosted in IIS you can fix the problem by setting 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' to true or specifying 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/baseAddressPrefixFilters'.
Parameter name: item
```

Comment: [UPDATE] I forced the values in UseDefaultWebProxy and BypassProxyOnLocal in the wsHttpBinding. But still have a problem with the NetTcpBinding as communication channel is in Faulted state.

Comment: How do you create the Core Service Client?